# Show some error Uncaught ReferenceError:

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

HI i have call a **json** file and show some error can u please help me

show  error `Uncaught ReferenceError: marketlivedata is not defined`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">

<head>
  <title>Data Call to json</title>



  <script type="text/javascript">
    // =====================
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      //    alert('hello');
      //  var marketlivedata ;
    });
     // =====================
    function getUserData() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx.json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) {
          //  $('#ajexLoaderSec').hide();
          console.log(data);

        },
        error: function(e) {
          alert("There is an error while connecting to the server. Please try after some time");
        }
      });
    };
    getUserData();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  gsdf sdf sdfsd sdf sd
</body>

</html>
```

My json format is

```
marketlivedata([{"sensex":{"trend":"equal","CloseIndexValue":"24893.81","premarket":"false","DateTime":"11:41 AM | 08 Sep 2015","CurrentIndexValue":"24958.31","Segment":"BSE","OpenIndexValue":"24972.01","PercentChange":"0.26","IndexName":"SENSEX","NetChange":"64.50"},"nifty":{"trend":"equal","CloseIndexValue":"7558.80","premarket":"false","DateTime":"11:41 AM | 08 Sep 2015","CurrentIndexValue":"7582.85","Segment":"NSE","OpenIndexValue":"7587.70","PercentChange":"0.32","IndexName":"CNX NIFTY","NetChange":"24.05"},"gold":{"ClosePrice":"26500.00","trend":"negative","OpenPrice":"26499.00","ExpiryDate":"2015-10-05","SpotSymbol":"SGOLDAHM","LastTradedPrice":"26441.00","DateTime":"8-September-2015 11:34:22","Symbol":"GOLD","PercentChange":"-0.22","CommodityName":"Gold","NetChange":"-59.00","PriceQuotationUnit":"10 GRMS ","SpotPrice":"26401.0"},"silver":{"ClosePrice":"35193.00","trend":"equal","OpenPrice":"35176.00","ExpiryDate":"2015-12-04","SpotSymbol":"SSILVERAHM","LastTradedPrice":"35070.00","DateTime":"8-September-2015 11:34:0","Symbol":"SILVER","PercentChange":"-0.35","CommodityName":"Silver","NetChange":"-123.00","PriceQuotationUnit":"1 KGS  ","SpotPrice":"34815.0"},"USD/INR":{"DateTime":"2015-09-08 11:36:02.0","percentChange":"-0.27","netChange":"-0.18","name":"USD/INR","bidprice":"66.65"},"DXY Index":{"DateTime":"2015-09-08 11:39:40.0","percentChange":"-0.1","netChange":"-0.1","name":"DXY Index","bidprice":"96.13"},"marketstatus":{"currentMarketStatus":"Live"}}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned data is `marketlivedata(...)`. This is calling the `marketlivedata` function, which is not defined in your script. Since, you've used dataType as `jsonp`, the function is executed.

To solve this you can change the data format from the JSON server(which might not be possible as this looks like third party service) or you can define a function of that name which will be called when the response has arrived.

```js
function getUserData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://mobilelivefeeds.indiatimes.com/homepagedatanew.json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
      //  $('#ajexLoaderSec').hide();
      console.log(data);

    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
};
getUserData();


function marketlivedata(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am just curious where did the function marketlivedata() appear? :)

Comment: @Pekka As you have read in the answer, it is in the response from the server

Comment: @Tushar Jai said to  check url but i cant seem to see it right now. If i click on run code would i be able to see the function. Sorry i just want to know where i can see the function.

Comment: @Pekka See the question OP has the response data under title `My json format is` which looks like `marketlivedata([{"sensex":{"trend":"equal",....`

Comment: @Tushar sorry i didn't see that one.. can i ask one more question; `console.log(data);` would have still show the data since it is a success?Why do you still need a `function marketlivedata(data) {` just to console the data return?

Comment: @Jai thanks for the link if the format is like this do you need to have a function for this?I am just curious because i just use console.log(data); on success and it works all the time. Only difference is i get the data from my own php page.Usually from sql query.

Comment: _Only difference is i get the data from my own php page._ This is not the case with OP because he wants to use data from third party website and this can only be available with `jsonp`. @pekka

Answer (score 2):

As you are using json data which comes from another domain so there would be a callback function needed to access this:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: marketlivedata is not defined*

Here `marketlivedata` is a *Callback Wrapper* function which is returned from the service you are hitting, so Either a reference of a global function has to be set with the name of `marketlivedata` or **make use of `jsonpCallback: 'callback'`***(much better one)* where `"callback"` is the function from the response. This function is actually carrying the data which you want to use, So this has to  be done:

```js
function getUserData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://mobilelivefeeds.indiatimes.com/homepagedatanew.json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'marketlivedata', // call the returned function here.
    success: function(data) {
           document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data) + '</pre>'; // use the data as you need to.
    }, // you can refere it here
    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
};
getUserData();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks i think i understand it now..The reason is that the data that is requested is inside `marketlivedata()` we can simply say that the data returned is `marketlivedata(data)` thus needing the function `marketlivedata` to get the data?Am i right?

Comment: So the format `sonp` requires a function to say unlock the data within?thats cool thanks for the info it help me im sure other will be helped to

Comment: Right! Actually that depends on the web link you are hitting, some may give you data and some may require to have a padding like a function.

Comment: @pekka `jsonp` where `p` stands for padding and that is a callback function wrapper to get access to the data.

Comment: @pekka : http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/ some basic things you can clear more from here. Read it out.