# Jquery autocomplete with JSONP not working

Tags: jquery, jsonp, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the below code for autocomplete:

```
jQuery('#id')
        .autocomplete({
            "select":function (event, ui) 
            {
                return false;
            },
            "focus":function(event, ui) 
            {
                return false;
            },
            "minLength":"3",
            "source":function( request, response ) 
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost/autocompleteex',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp: "jsonp-callback",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: {
                        search:request.term, 
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map( data, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.value
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                       console.log(' Status : '+ JSON.stringify(msg));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Server return the JSON string as:

```
"jQuery111305726958822940869_1443857160714([{\"value\":\"IKlaAbB77L36ovoVTIHWzWaAbB77m0kJ6XsjPMsl6i7oIz2TVPxt8s6eC7rEt
\",\"label\":\"A Fantis Parochial School, BROOKLYN NY\"}]);"
```

Am I missing anything. It always shows error console log. Any idea?

Comment: check Jai's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450690/show-some-error-uncaught-referenceerror it might help you

Comment: i think you are missing the `jsonpCallback`

Comment: tried that .. Cant get it to work :(

Comment: it doesnt go into success .. shows the error function console log

Comment: I am using GET method

Comment: my guess is your data is not the type of your dataType if you can check it and change it then i will return something in the success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91227/discussion-between-chinmay-and-pekka).