# How to resolve jsonCallback is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am doing two ajax calls as shown in this

```
$(document).one('pagebeforeshow', '#customerpage', function(event) 
             {
                 var showt1sajaxquery = $.ajax({
                     type: 'GET',
                     url: url + '/xxxx?id=' + id,
                     jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                     dataType: 'jsonp',
                     timeout: 6000,
                     jsonp: false,
                     cache: false,
                          async: false,
                     success: function(response) {
                     },
                     error: function(x, t, m) {
                     }
                 });
                 showt1sajaxquery.done(function() {
                     $.ajax({
                         type: 'GET',
                         url: url + '/xxxx?screen_ids=' + screen_id,
                         jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                         cache: false,
                         dataType: 'jsonp',
                         jsonp: false,
                         timeout: 7000,
                              async: false,
                         success: function(response) {

                         },
                         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                             $("#loaderforindex").hide();
                         }
                     })
                 }).done(function() {
                    sessionlogic('generic');
                 }); //

             }); // ready ends
```

I guess the problem is due to the ajax responses getting mixed up .

Could you please let em know how can i ensure that i will get rid of this error

Uncaught TypeError: jsonCallback is not a function

Comment: i think you need to have a callback in the response if you dont have that maybe that is the reason

Comment: check here maybe it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450690/show-some-error-uncaught-referenceerror

Comment: Thanks for the information  chnaged the name of jsonpCallback to some other name which actually resolved the issue .

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to change the URL to start with // instead of http:// or https://