# jQuery JSONP callback function not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to get data from external server using JSONP, but I've stuck on the callback function.

```
function processLinks(data) {
    alert('IT WORKS!');
};

function getLinks() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://external-site.com/test.cgi',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
};
```

When I call getLinks(), I get `ReferenceError: processLinks is not defined`.

External site returns `processLinks({"mark": "dog", "number":"33"});`.

Thank you for any help

Comment: **getLinks()** function doesn't have **processLinks** function, then how can it give `ReferenceError: processLinks is not defined`

Comment: Where you are calling the `processLinks` function?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450690/show-some-error-uncaught-referenceerror it might help

Comment: @MokshShah I've tried to put it inside the getLinks() function with no luck.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I do not explicitly. Its callback in JSONP format.

Comment: @guradio I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: You don't need to end function with `;`.